# convert clob to varchar python

Tags: python, database, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have this code to create table and import the data to the Oracle DB

```
# Connect to DB
conn = connect_to_oracle(user_db, pw_db)
connection = conn.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Setting Param
test = pd.read_csv(r"template.csv",
                   dtype={'updated_date':'str'})

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE customers_test
( updated_date VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  id_1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  id_2 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  score float(10) NOT NULL,
  lvl VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  sgmt VARCHAR2(10))
''')
```

After that I used the to_sql function to import_data

```
test.to_sql('CUSTOMER_TEST', engine, schema, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

However when I check on DB I saw that almost all the columns were turned into CLOB

```
UPDATED_DATE, CLOB
ID_1, CLOB
ID_2, CLOB
TYPE, CLOB
SCORE, FLOAT
LVL, CLOB
SGMT, CLOB
```

So I want to know how to convert all columns into varchar2? How to prevent them becoming CLOB? Thank you

Comment: Can you please check 2 moments: 1. DB you're running your code is the same DB you're checking table definition (I'm not joking, such I had this problem for many times); 2. Please try to explicitly drop the table and run your code afterwards. If it has no data already of course

Comment: @ekochergin I have checked again the DB and my code. That's the same DB. I also dropped that table and tried to run the code again. However, the result are the same

Comment: what version of cx_Oracle and python are you using ?

Comment: I am using cx_Oracle 8.0 python 3.7 on my client side, and Oracle 19.6 in database side. I run your code and I can't reproduce your issue. In my case it works without any issue and the columns are created as varchar2

Comment: Now I know why. When I used to_sql funciton from sqlalchemy, I did not specify dtype for each column in the table. => Solution: add dtype and run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal conditions, the code should work without any issue

Python sample code

```
import cx_Oracle

host="ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP"
port=60995
sid='odcgrc1r'
user='CPL_REP'
password='Cpl3_r3p'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, sid, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE customers_test
( updated_date VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  id_1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  id_2 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  score float(10) NOT NULL,
  lvl VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  sgmt VARCHAR2(10))
''')
```

Now I execute a tnsping to my database, run the python code and connect by `sqlplus` to verify the table structure

```
C:\python>tnsping ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/odcgrc1r

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 29-SEP-2021 10:51:34

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Parameterdateien benutzt:
C:\Programme\Oracle\11.2.0\client\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Adapter HOSTNAME zur Aufl÷sung des Alias benutzt
Verbindungsversuch mit (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=odcgrc1r))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=180.22.128.47)(PORT=60995)))
OK (140 ms)

C:\python> C:\python>tnsping ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/odcgrc1r

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 29-SEP-2021 10:51:34

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Parameterdateien benutzt:
C:\Programme\Oracle\11.2.0\client\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Adapter HOSTNAME zur Aufl÷sung des Alias benutzt
Verbindungsversuch mit (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=odcgrc1r))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=180.22.128.47)(PORT=60995)))
OK (140 ms)

C:\python> python testconn.py

C:\python>sqlplus cpl_rep/Cpl3_r3p@//ODCGRC1R.SCGER.DEV.CORP:60995/odcgrc1r

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Sep 29 10:52:48 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Sep 29 2021 10:47:26 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> desc cpl_rep.customers_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 UPDATED_DATE                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 ID_1                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 ID_2                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 TYPE                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 SCORE                                     NOT NULL FLOAT(10)
 LVL                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 SGMT                                               VARCHAR2(10)
```

But if you don't specify the right `dtype` in the `to_sql` function, you can get this behaviour, as it has been stated by the question's poster.

Comment: Thank you, I finally found out that I did not specify dtype in to_sql function. After I modify my code, the formats are correct.

Comment: @Long_NgV, good to know. it was really strange indeed.

Comment: @Long_NgV, I would put your comment in the answer, that others might get help of it. If you are so kind, please accept the answer.

Comment: Done, just add the dtype part in your answer so everyone will see how to solve this problem